# How to connect SQL server 2008 R2 in php 5.4 with xampp

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, xampp

I am using Xampp with Php 5.4 (Zend studio) and download sqlserver driver download V3.0 for php 5.4

I followed [this URL](http://sl33py.web.id/2013/01/10/setup-php-with-sql-server-2008/).

I Configured all steps above URL but still I cannot connection open and error came..

```
Connection could not be established.

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct enter code here and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ))
```

Please give solution for above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start \ Microsoft SQL Server 2008 \ Configuration Tools \ SQL Server Configuration Manager,then SQL Native Client Configuration, Client Protocols and check that shared memory, tcp/ip and named pipes are enabled.

I`m writing this as an answer because I cant comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

*(Don't mean to resurrect an old post, but just in case others are looking for the answer, and because this post came up during my search...)*

A short step-by-step guide to connect to SQL_server from PHP on XAMPP using native driver:

1. First of all download PHP for SQL_server Microsoft native driver from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 Take care to choose the one that fits your setup.
2. Install it to the PHP extension directory (typically in `c:\xampp\php\ext`).
3. Configure the new extension in `PHP.ini` (typically in `C:\xampp\php`) by uncommenting or appending the line (depending on the choosen driver version). I.e.:

   ```
   extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
   ```
4. Restart Apache from XAMPP control panel (stop + start).

   Now your PHP setup is able to connect to SQL_server databases. Adapt following code to test it with your own database:

   ```
   <?php
   $server = "SERVER\SQLEXPRESS";
   $database = "test_database";
   $user = "test_user";
   $pwd = "test_password";

   $options = array(  "UID" => $user,  "PWD" => $pwd,  "Database" => $database);
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);

   if ($conn === false) {
       die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
   echo "Successfully connected!";

   $sql = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM dbo.table_name";
   $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
   if ($query === false) {
       exit("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }

   while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))  {
       echo "<p>$row[field1] $row[field2]</p>";
   }

   sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
   sqlsrv_close($conn);
   ```

---

*Tested from XAMPP 3.2.1 and XAMPP 5.6.14 on SQL_server 2008 R2 and SQL_server 2014 express.*